# Infinite Scrolling Sunspot With Kaminari Gem and Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sunspot, kaminari

I am trying run this infinite scroll but for me not working fine.

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery

I am using [sunspot with kaminari gem](https://github.com/richardiux/sunspot_with_kaminari) that paginate fine the results.

**But when I trying create the infinite scroll with this tutorial. I get that when the scroll arrive the page down, repeat the result of the second page many times, but the results for the page 3,4,5 and the next page dont are showed.**

repeats the second page results as many times as you have results per page in your controller, for example: if you have in your controller index action:

```
paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 8
```

Repeat 8 times the same second page with the same results.

Comment: Then problem its fixed I have used http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ for paginate its very easy.

Comment: would you be willing to show an example of infinite scroll with rails?  I've tried to add it (new programmer) but the instructions are lacking.

Comment: May you provide your full code of how did you have resolved with infinite-scrolling, please?